# Adding a pvalue column to dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3
0  1  0  2  3  3
5  6  4  4  6  6
```

I would like to add a column based on t-testing the significance of the difference between As and Bs:

```
A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 PValue
0  1  0  3  3  4  <some small number>
5  6  4  4  6  6  <some large number>
```

I tried using dplyr like this:

```
data %>% 
    mutate(PValue = t.test(unlist(c(A1,A2,A3),unlist(c(B1,B2,B3)))$p.value)
```

However, the resulting PValue column is constant for some reason. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are doing this by row, then `pmap` is one way

```
library(tidyverse)
pmap_dbl(data, ~ c(...) %>% 
                   {t.test(.[1:3], .[4:6])$p.value}) %>% 
     bind_cols(data, PValue = .)
#   A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3      PValue
#1  0  1  0  2  3  3 0.007762603
#2  5  6  4  4  6  6 0.725030185
```

---

or another option is `rowwise` with `do`

```
data %>%
   rowwise() %>% 
   do(data.frame(., PValue = t.test(unlist(.[1:3]), unlist(.[4:6]))$p.value))
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#     A1    A2    A3    B1    B2    B3  PValue
#* <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
#1     0     1     0     2     3     3 0.00776
#2     5     6     4     4     6     6 0.725
```

---

Or we can `gather` to 'long' format and then do the group by `t.test`

```
data %>%
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
  gather(key, val, -rn) %>% group_by(rn) %>% 
  summarise(PValue = t.test(val[str_detect(key, "A")],
                           val[str_detect(key, "B")])$p.value) %>% 
  pull(PValue) %>% 
  bind_cols(data, PValue = .)
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(A1 = c(0L, 5L), A2 = c(1L, 6L), A3 = c(0L, 4L), 
B1 = c(2L, 4L), B2 = c(3L, 6L), B3 = c(3L, 6L)), .Names = c("A1", 
"A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you comment on the comparative efficiency when working with large data?

Comment: @Novice I would go with `pmap` compared to `do` or `gather`.  For `gather`, there is the inefficiency of conversion to long format and `do` is not so fast

Answer (score 2):

Also with `apply` in Base R:

```
data$PValue = apply(data, 1, function(x) t.test(x[1:3], x[4:6])$p.value)
```

or:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(PValue = apply(., 1, function(x) t.test(x[1:3], x[4:6])$p.value))
```

**Result:**

```
  A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3      PValue
1  0  1  0  2  3  3 0.007762603
2  5  6  4  4  6  6 0.725030185
```

Comment: Since `apply` internally coerces to a matrix, calling it on data frames is a bad habit, as it will sometimes cause type errors. A more robust (but hard to read) base version of `pmap` is `do.call(mapply, c(function(...) t.test(c(...)[1:3], c(...)[4:6])$p.value, data))`

Comment: @alistaire Good point, but in this case, we **do** know that `data` would be all numeric, since that is required for `t.test` to work properly. Hence, `apply` coercing the data.frame to matrix is a non-issue (at least for this problem). It all depends on context and your end goal.